# Inserting a Custom Search Bar in WordPress Header Using WPCode Plugin

Tags: html, wordpress, search

I'm trying to insert a custom search bar into the header of my WordPress site using the WPCode plugin. The WPCode plugin allows for code insertion into the  tag of the site. However, I'm unsure how to position the search bar specifically in the header area. Here's the code I've attempted to use:

```html
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
    <label>
        <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Search …" value="" name="s" />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

I placed this code in the WPCode settings to insert into the  tag. However, on reviewing my site, the search bar was not inserted.

TLDR; I am using salient as a theme and would like to insert a custom search bar that redirects to another page into my navbar. How can I achieve this?